# Finding NVCC on Server

Tags: nvidia, cuda, gpu, python-2.7

I am using a server that I don't have sudo powers on.  I want to do GPU computing in Python using the theano back end.  It seems that I need to have the "nvcc" program and set it in my path.  However, I can't find it.  I'm not sure if that means it does not exist.

I can run nvidia-smi and apt shows that I have libcuda installed.  This suggests to me that the CUDA GPU toolkit has been installed.  I would think, then, that nvcc should be around too.

Most online resources indicate that nvcc is in /usr/local or /usr/lib but I can't find it there.

Installation information on the internet says the computer needs to be reset after installing nvcc, which I can't do.

I am trying to follow these two pages:
http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/using_gpu.html 
http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_ubuntu.html#gpu-linux

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

"I can run nvidia-smi and apt shows that I have libcuda"

```
# Where (in $PATH) is nvidia-smi?
type -p nvidia-smi

# what package is nvidia-smi in?
dpkg -S $(type -p nvidia-smi)

# What files were installed by that package, and where?
dpkg -L $(dpkg -S $(type -p nvidia-smi) | cut -d: -f1 )

# Where was nvidia-smi when updatedb was last run (maybe never)
locate nvidia-smi
```

A similar approach will tell you about `libcuda`. No `sudo` required thus far.

**HOWEVER**, you say "I am using a server that I don't have sudo powers on".

Your attempt to "do GPU computing" will FAIL without the co-operation of the system administrator.

Comment: Thanks.  We have permission to do so generally, they just don't work on Sundays and may not respond to my question immediately. I am under pressure to get things moving as soon as possible.